# How to get sum of particular class for particular name items

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

currently I have

```
var cost = document.getElementsByName('blog_linkm_one[]');
            
for (var i = 0; i < cost.length; i++) {
  sum += parseFloat(cost[i].value);
}
```

This function gives me sum of all `text box` name as `blog_linkm_one[]` and it is working.

Now I want to filter it out.

I have some different classes like `appending_div0`, `appending_div1`, `appending_div2` and all those classes have textboxes name sd `blog_linkm_one[]`.

What I want is to get sum of relevant `blog_linkm_one[]` as per their particular class.

For example

class `appending_div0` has 3 text box `blog_linkm_one[]`. And their value is `1`, `2`, `3`, So their sum has to be `6`

class `appending_div1` has 5 text box `blog_linkm_one[]`. And their value is `1`, `2`, `3`, `5`, `9` So their sum has to be `20`.

Comment: Instead of describing the HTML, please just add it to the question. Then we can create a working example from it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really understand the question. You have different HTML tags which can have one of these css classes. And all the textboxes that have name="blog_linkm_one[]" have numbers as values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of the possible answers ...

```js
const cls = ['appending_div0','appending_div1','appending_div2']

let sum = { any:0 }

document.querySelectorAll('input[name="blog_linkm_one[]"]').forEach(el=>
  {
  sum.any += parseFloat(el.value)

  cls.forEach(cl=>
    {
    if (el.classList.contains(cl))
      {
      sum[cl] = (sum[cl] ?? 0) + parseFloat(el.value)
      }  
    })
  })

console.log( sum )
```

```html
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="" value="10000" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div0" value="1" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div0" value="2" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div0" value="3" >

<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div1" value="1" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div1" value="2" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div1" value="3" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div1" value="5" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div1" value="9" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div2" value="4" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div2" value="5" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="appending_div2" value="6" >
<input type="text" name="blog_linkm_one[]" class="" value="20000" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is tagged [jQuery], so here's a (partially) jQuery answer involving a chain comprising:

- [jQuery's $(selector, context)](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context)
- [jQuery's .map() method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)
- [jQuery's .get() method](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get2)
- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Here's your basic utility :-

```
function filterAndSummate(elements, className) {
    return $(`.${className}`, elements) // filter
    .map((i, element) => parseFloat($(element).val())) // map filtered elements to values
    .get() // convert jQuery object to Array
    .reduce((x, value) => x + value, 0); // summate the values
}
```

Now three ways in which you might want to call `filterAndSummate()`

1. Each sum as an individual variable :-

```
    var costElements = document.getElementsByName('blog_linkm_one[]');
    let cost_1 = filterAndSummate(costElements, 'appending_div0');
    let cost_2 = filterAndSummate(costElements, 'appending_div1');
    let cost_3 = filterAndSummate(costElements, 'appending_div2');
```

2. All sums in an array :-

```
    var costElements = document.getElementsByName('blog_linkm_one[]');
    let costs = ['appending_div0', 'appending_div1', 'appending_div2'] // array of classNames
                .map(className => filterAndSummate(costElements, className)); // map to array of costs (one per className)
```

3. All sums added together to make a grand-total :-

```
    var costElements = document.getElementsByName('blog_linkm_one[]');
    let grand_total = ['appending_div0', 'appending_div1', 'appending_div2'] // array of classNames
                      .map(className => filterAndSummate(costElements, className)) // map to array of costs (one per className)
                      .reduce((x, c) => x + c, 0); // summate all the costs to get a grand-total
```